# Optimize a very large two-level deep iteration

Tags: c#, c++, loops, optimization, iteration

I am wondering for a while how can I optimize even more this two-level deep iteration. It iterates 1 million times each time, for 1 million times. I tried to shave off some time by using i and j variable creating only inside their respective loops and also cached the value fetched from container1[i] into c1 to not search the container every time. Is there any more optimizations anyone can think off??

```
float add = 0.0f;
int limit = 1000000;
for (int i = 0; i != limit; ++i) {
    int c1 = container1[i];
    for (int j = 0; j != limit; ++j) {
        add += c1 * container2[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you serious? There is no reason to nest those loops. Just calculate the sum of `container1` and the sum of `container2`, and then multiply those two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have nested loops, you could just calculate multiplication of two sums:

```
float add = container1.Sum() * container2.Sum();
```